# Application Context is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections Spring AMQP

Tags: spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I have implemented multi threading to perform some operation in jira once i consume the message from rabbitmq. I am using spring amqp (version 1.6.1)

Once the thread catches the exception, i am setting status as an error and output object i am referring in future. While sending this output object to the queue. I am facing above execption

Code :

Connection Factory:

```
@Configuration
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") })
public class RabbitMQConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public ConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {

        // TODO make it possible to customize in subclasses.
        CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new CachingConnectionFactory(environment.getProperty("bip.rabbitmq.url"));
        connectionFactory.setUsername(environment.getProperty("bip.rabbitmq.username"));
        connectionFactory.setPassword(environment.getProperty("bip.rabbitmq.password"));
        return connectionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jsonMessageConverter() {
        return new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter();
    }

    /**
     * @return the admin bean that can declare queues etc.
     */
    @Bean
    public AmqpAdmin amqpAdmin() {
        RabbitAdmin rabbitAdmin = new RabbitAdmin(connectionFactory());
        return rabbitAdmin;
    }

    @Bean
    public RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate() {
        RabbitTemplate template = new RabbitTemplate(connectionFactory());
        template.setMessageConverter(jsonMessageConverter());
        return template;
    }

    @Bean(name = "jiraQueueListenerContainerFactory")
    public SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory jiraQueueListenerContainerFactory() {
        SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory factory = new SimpleRabbitListenerContainerFactory();
        factory.setConnectionFactory(connectionFactory());
        factory.setMessageConverter(new Jackson2JsonMessageConverter());
        factory.setReceiveTimeout(10L);
        return factory;
    }

}
```

MessageHandler :

```
@Component
@PropertySources({ @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") })

public class JiraMessageHandler {

    @Autowired
    private RabbitTemplate rabbitTemplate;

    private static ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(Constants.THREAD_SIZE);

    private static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(JiraMessageHandler.class);

    @RabbitListener(containerFactory = "jiraQueueListenerContainerFactory", queues = Constants.QUEUE_NAME)
    public void handleMessage(HashMap<String, Object> jiraMessage) {

        logger.info(jiraMessage.toString() + System.currentTimeMillis());
        logger.info("Jira Message Handler");
        BaseServerAdapter jiraProcessingAdapter = new JiraProcessingAdapter();
        Future future = executor.submit(jiraProcessingAdapter);
        JiraAdapterOutput jiraAdapterOutput = new JiraAdapterOutput();
        Future future = executor.submit(jiraProcessingAdapter);
        jiraAdapterOutput = (JiraAdapterOutput) future.get();
        try {
            jiraAdapterOutput = (JiraAdapterOutput) future.get();

            if (jiraAdapterOutput.getOutputMap().get("activityStatus") == "SUCCESS") {
                logger.info("Successfully Executed Jira ::: " + new Date() + "::: "
                        + jiraAdapterOutput.getOutputMap().get("jiraId"));
                        rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.ADAPTER_OUTPUT_QUEUE, senderMap);
            }else if (jiraAdapterOutput.getOutputMap().get("activityStatus").equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {
                logger.info("Successfully Executed Jira ::: " + new Date() + "::: "
                        + jiraAdapterOutput.getOutputMap().get("jiraId"));
                        sendMessageForProcessingToBIP(senderMap);
            }

        private boolean sendMessageForProcessingToBIP(HashMap<String, ExchangeDTO> senderMap) {
        try {
            rabbitTemplate.convertAndSend(Constants.WFM_ERROR_QUEUE, senderMap);
            return true;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            **logger.info("Message sending failed, try again:::::::" + e.getMessage());**
        }
        return false;

    }
```

It is showing **"Application Context is closed and the ConnectionFactory can no longer create connections."**

Anything wrong I am doing.
I referred here as well : https://jira.spring.io/browse/AMQP-546

Answer (score 0):

The code above (in handleMessage) looks incomplete - there is no catch for the try.

You must be closing the application context elsewhere before attempting the send. You can't use beans in the context after it is closed/destroyed. The JIRA you reference was to allow such access in `stop()` methods in other beans - i.e. destroy the connection only after all other beans have stopped.

I suggest you turn on DEBUG logging for `org.springframework` and figure out why the context is being closed prematurely.

Comment: Sorry for not adding catch block. If the Issue is getting in Jira, i am able to send the message. At that moment, i am having rabbittemplate **contextclosed as false**. But when it fails to create an issue in jira due to some missing parameters, it goes to catch block there it shows **contextclosed as true** because from there i am sending to error queue.

Comment: As I said, to get that exception you must be closing the context. Turn on DEBUG logging. I can't help without that log.

Comment: ok. Could you please let me know how to turn on DEBUG logging. Sometimes when i get the message on first line of logger, i am checking connection, there also **contextclosed as true**

Comment: Refer to your logging subsystem documentation. log4j, logback etc. I have no idea what you mean by contextclosed as true.

Comment: I found out, `@EnableRabbit` annotation was missing in my configuration.
Now it worked!